# Plotting multiple layers with geom_raster() or geom_tile or geom_rect()

Tags: r, image-processing, plot, ggplot2, raster

I have a data.frame of b/w raster image data that I'm using as a background/base layer.  It has three columns: x, y, z.  Where x and y are the respective coordinates and z is a continuous value defining a 512 x 512 image.  I set this background fill to a black-white gradient and plot using `geom_raster()` in `ggplot2` and then save the image to a PDF file.

```
### MWE of base layer
# original 512x512 data is read in from a file in matrix format, so here's a mocked up example of same:
h = matrix(data = rep(c(1:512), 512), byrow = T, nrow = 512, ncol = 512)

# convert to data.frame with all the rows of z-data in first column
h = data.frame(z = as.vector(t(h)))

# create equally spaced 512x512 x and y pixel coordinate vectors
x = c(-255:256)
y = c(-255:256)

# add x and y coordinate vectors to the data.frame
h$x = rep(t(x), 512)
h$y = rep(t(-y), each=512)

# plot the data
ggplot() + 
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_raster(data=h, aes(x,y,fill=z)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="black", high="white", na.value="transparent")

# save to png   
ggsave("testbaseplot.png", dpi=300)
```

This gives the desired result in the saved file.

[image: BasePlot]

---

Next, on top of that base layer I plot one or more additional layers. These layers also have x, y, and r. Where r is either a continuous or discrete value depending on the region.  For example, a layer defining region borders would label the discrete regions, whereas a layer defining topology in the region would define the topology.

Ideally, I'd like to use `geom_raster()` twice, once for each layer (base, overlay) and use a different `aes(fill=)` on each layer, with a different `scale_fill_*()` for each layer as well.  However, attempting this results in errors:

```
# MWE of mock overlay = 4 square labeled regions
# create z-data for some example shapes
r = data.frame(r = as.vector(c(rep(rep(c('a','b'),each=100),100),
                               rep(rep(c('c','d'),each=100),100))))

# create x and y coordinates 
r$x = rep(c(-99:100),200)
r$y = rep(c(-99:100),each=200)

# plot base layer and 1 overlay layer, both as geom_raster
ggplot() + 
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_raster(data=h, aes(x,y,fill=z)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="black", high="white", na.value="transparent") + 
  geom_raster(data=r, aes(x,y,fill=r)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","white","blue","yellow"))
```

Error Message:

> Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale.
>    Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

---

I thought maybe I could do one `geom_raster()` with `aes(fill=z)` and one with the `aes(colour=r)` and `scale_colour_manual` but `geom_raster()` does not recognize the `aes(colour=)` option, so I used `geom_tile(aes(colour=r))` instead:

```
# plot looks fine
ggplot() + 
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_raster(data=h, aes(x,y,fill=z)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="black", high="white", na.value="transparent") + 
  geom_tile(data=r, aes(x,y,colour=r), fill="transparent") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","white","blue","yellow"))

# saved file does not
ggsave("testlayerplot.png", dpi=300)
```

The plot looks fine in RStudio's previewer window, but when saved as a file (pdf, png, etc.), the tile layer has a grid of unwanted lines on it.
[image: Layer Plot]

I believe these lines are showing up because the `geom_tile` default fill is grey.  Is this due to the file format?  Due to the default grey fill of `geom_tile` ignoring the `fill="transparent"` option?  Some other reason?

---

I feel like I am approaching this wrong.  I am probably converting the original raster data in matrix format into x,y,z `data.frame` format unnecessarily... and because I understand `data.frame` format better.

**First part:** Can I use `ggplot` to plot one raster over another without getting the unwanted lines?  If so, how?  Can I also add an `alpha=.5` transparency to the overlay layer?

**Second part:**  Is there a way that I can plot the original raster matrix format without converting to x,y,z `data.frame` format first? If so, how?  Can I set transparency on the overlay layer?

Comment: I've tried that as well but haven't found any size that does not have the lines in the saved file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little work, you can use `annotate` to create the background *without* mapping, so the fill scales remains available for the center:

```
h$z <- (h$z - min(h$z)) / diff(range(h$z))
ggplot() + 
  coord_fixed() +
  annotate(
    geom = 'raster', 
    x = h$x, 
    y = h$y, 
    fill = scales::colour_ramp(c("black", "white"))(h$z)
  ) +
  geom_raster(aes(x, y, fill = r), data = r) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "white", "blue", "yellow"))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool!  But what if I have more than one overlay layer?

Comment: Depends, either map them to a common scale, or abuse `annotate` a little further.

Comment: nice benefit of this is that it renders WAY faster than using `geom_tile`